# Find and Replace for whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, replace, find

I'm trying to create a Find and Replace for the whole page.

I'm Using findandreplace which is a mini-plugin which is:

```
function findAndReplace(searchText, replacement, searchNode) {
    if (!searchText || typeof replacement === 'undefined') {
       alert("Please Enter Some Text Into the Field");
        return;
    }
    var regex = typeof searchText === 'string' ?
                new RegExp(searchText, 'g') : searchText,
        childNodes = (searchNode || document.body).childNodes,
        cnLength = childNodes.length,
        excludes = 'html,head,style,title,link,meta,script,object,iframe';
    while (cnLength--) {
        var currentNode = childNodes[cnLength];
        if (currentNode.nodeType === 1 &&
            (excludes + ',').indexOf(currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ',') === -1) {
            arguments.callee(searchText, replacement, currentNode);
        }
        if (currentNode.nodeType !== 3 || !regex.test(currentNode.data) ) {
            continue;
        }
        var parent = currentNode.parentNode,
            frag = (function(){
                var html = currentNode.data.replace(regex, replacement),
                    wrap = document.createElement('div'),
                    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
                wrap.innerHTML = html;
                while (wrap.firstChild) {
                    frag.appendChild(wrap.firstChild);
                }
                return frag;
            })();
        parent.insertBefore(frag, currentNode);
        parent.removeChild(currentNode);
    }
}
```

At the moment I need the find button to make a seperate JS for each Item found. I have made it so it adds a different random ID for each found item. Now I just need the JS. When Im done with the whole this I will want it so when you click on one of the found words it has a popup(not alert) saying: "Replace Word with: {INPUT HERE}" Then it will replace just that word. I thought that would be cool.

My find code is:

```
document.getElementById('find').onsubmit = function() {
    findAndReplace(document.getElementById('fText').value, function(hi) {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999);
        var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);

        $('#fade').after('<span id="show' + n + '" style="display:none;"></span>');
        $('#show' + n + '').html(hi);
        $('body').prepend("<script type='text/javascript'>$('#highlight" + n + "').click(function(){$('#fade').show();});$('#highlight" + n + "').mouseover(function(){$('#highlight" + n + "').css('background', 'blue');});$('#highlight" + n + "').mouseout(function(){$('#highlight" + n + "').css('background', 'yellow');});</sc" + "ript>");
        return '<span id="highlight' + n + '" style="background: yellow;color: black;">' + hi + '</span>';

    });
    return false;
};
```

I figured out that .html cant place `<script>` tags into a document so I hope there is another way I can do this.
Its a little crazy looking. Mabye you can see it better and know what I want [here](http://jsfiddle.net/czZKD/3/)

I hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: the above findAndReplace function is not accurate give a try with "a" or anchor tag. It will fail. You should improve its exclusion method by replacing excludes with excludes = ['html','head','style','title','link','meta','script','object','iframe']; and use includes instead of indexOf for matching within array 
like this !excludes.includes(currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase()). This is off-topic but will help you to improve your traversing method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following code at the end of your script. It takes input from a prompt but it will 'replace all', not just the one that you click.

```
$('span[id^=highlight]').live('click', function () {
    replacePrompt = prompt('Replace Word with:','{INPUT HERE}');
    findAndReplace(document.getElementById('fText').value, function() {
        return '<span class="highlight2" style="background: white;color: black;">' + replacePrompt + '</span>';
    });
    return false;
})
```

Maybe I can work something out after going through your `findAndReplace` function..

UPDATE: A solution is to not use the `findAndReplace` plugin at all. I am still not sure but this is probably what you want.

```
$('span[id^=highlight]').live('click', function () {
    replacePrompt = prompt('Replace Word with:','{INPUT HERE}');
    $(this).text(replacePrompt);
})
```